# How do I create a map from a class in order to extract its properties as values?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, type-safety

I would like to create a stronger type-safe link between an Angular template and a FormGroup. I thought of the following but I do not know how to express it in TypeScript properly.

I want to use an object to set **the keys** of the `controls` object of a **FormGroup** (the first parameter of the `FormControl` constructor), **as well as the binding of the `formControlName`** in the template, starting from a model class.

My reasoning is that this will remove the "stringy" or so-called **magic string** API arising from using strings for the `formControlName` attribute. This way, the single source of truth would be the model class. This would also allow me to easily refactor that class and have all other references update.

For example, I would have liked to be able to write something like this:

```js
// model class:
class Partner {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

// some static type SomeType = { id: "id", name: "name" } extends Partner's public properties
// but the values of those properties must equal the property name.

// component:
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
      <!-- notice I'm not using a stringy API like formControlName="id" -->
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="SomeType.id">
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="SomeType.name">
    </form>
`})
class CreatePartnerComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    SomeType.id: new FormControl(''),
    SomeType.name: new FormControl('')
  });
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found a (one) way.

```js
class ModelClass {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

// for the template I need a literal object that I can access by key
// and provide form control names as strings to bind the formControlName
// directive to, so I declare this inside the component class:

readonly fcName: { [key in keyof ModelClass]: key } = {
  // the problem with this is you need to explicitly declare the properties here and
  // keep this property up to date when you refactor ModelClass, but you still
  // get an error if you forget to, so that's great.
  // Also some IDEs can auto-fill these properties along with the values as well.
  id: 'id',
  name: 'name'
}

// and bind form controls like [formControlName]="fcName.id" and so on,
// in the template, this should be pretty obvious by now.

// and the form group you now declare like this, which
// enforces correct key names based on the model:

form = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(''),
  name: new FormControl('')
} as { [key in keyof ModelClass]: FormControl });
```

Any other more elegant way to do this that perhaps doesn't require creating that `fcNames` (form control names) variable, just for binding the correct names of the form controls in the template? It's duplicate code I'd love to eliminate if possible.

Comment: @IAfanasov that's almost an exact copy of my answer in terms of approach yet it does not show how you take care of the template bindings. Are you fishing for reputation? Why would you use imgur links for code?!

Comment: because it is not that easy to read the multiline code in comments and I don't have a full solution to publish as an answer (:

Comment: and that's how the template binding would be solved: `<input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls.id">`. as you can see from the https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r2yG.png, the `form.controls` would be typed

Comment: @IAfanasov, no, I'm sorry but `form.controls` is typed as `{ [p: string]: AbstractControl }`. There's no type information about the names `p` can take. You should read my question again and tell me what you don't understand because by now you've wasted your time giving multiple answers, none good enough or completely answering my question. For example you've completely ignored the template bindings aspect of my question, on several of your tries, even though I pointed that out.

Comment: I see my previous comments were deleted and the last comment doesn't make sense anymore. I updated my answer with the full code. I hope the idea finally would be clear (: That idea just appeared after I saw your answer. I haven't tried it and I don't have a real project with forms right now to try it out. I am genuinely interested to know if it would work well. If you would try it, I would be very thankful for a feedback. cheers (:

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but looks like you can simply use the `setValue` method like this to get this done. `this.formGroup.setValue(this.preFilledData)`

Answer (score -1):

That's is a really good practice to avoid so-called `magic string`. The possible solution might be:

```js
class ModelClass {
    id: string;
    age: number;
}
class MyFormGroup extends FormGroup {
    controls: {
        [key in keyof ModelClass]: AbstractControl;
    };
}
@Component({
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="form"
              (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
              novalidate>
            <input type="text"
                   [formControl]="form.controls.id" />
            <input type="text"
                   [formControlName]="form.controls.age" />
        </form>
    `,
})
class CreatePartnerComponent {
    someEnum = MyFormGroup; // trick to use enum inside the template
    formConfig: { [key in keyof ModelClass]: FormControl } = {
        id: new FormControl(),
        age: new FormControl(),
    };
    form = new FormGroup(this.formConfig) as MyFormGroup;
}
```

Comment: You're using types as values. That's invalid TypeScript.

Comment: I thought `SomeType` is an enum %) so get used to it that even didn't read properly (:

Comment: while it seems valid. I don't notice an issue

Comment: and the approach you suggested is way better than mine. thanks for sharing!

Comment: sorry but even after editing your answer, you are not using a model class. An enum is not a valid model.